# Trying to pass a method "GetYears" in my Index HomeController to used in my view. Then iterate through it to place each month in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

> Trying to send GetYears() to my Index view to loop through it and place the years into each checkbox. I can't seem to be able to loop through the list in my html page.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

       var tenYears = ViewBag.GetYears(10);

        return View(tenYears);
    }



private List<int> GetYears(int yearRange)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-yearRange).Year, 
        yearRange).ToList();
    }
```

```html
@foreach (int year in tenYears )
            {
                
            }

            <div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container2">
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.yearRange[0]</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years1</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years2</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years3</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years4</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years5</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years6</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years7</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years8</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years9</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years10</label>
            </div>
            <button id="selection" class="select-all-years">Select All Years</button>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the right way to do it.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.TenYears = GetYears(10);
    return View();
}
```

And then inside view.

```
<div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container2">
@foreach (var year in ViewBag.TenYears){
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="@year"> @year</label>
}
</div>
<button id="selection" class="select-all-years">Select All Years</button>
```

Points to always remember regarding viewbag:

- ViewBag transfers data from the controller to the view, ideally
  temporary data which in not included in a model. You can assign any
  number of propertes and values to ViewBag The ViewBag's life only
  lasts during the current http request. ViewBag values will be null if
  redirection occurs. ViewBag is actually a wrapper around ViewData.